# What does "positive mass point" mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm reading the book "An introduction to probability and statistics" by Rohatgi and I found with this concept in a definition.

[image]

I'm not understand the statement "The points of $E$ that have positive mass". I never heard about "points with positive mass". Before this point, the book never talk about probability mass functions, a concept that I know that exists in probability theory.
Maybe it is beacause I'm not an English native speaker and is a problem of translate (I'm Spanish speaker, from Argentina).

Some explanation of the notation:

\begin{align*}
P\{ X \in E \} = P \left[ \{x \in \mathcal{R} : X(x) \in E \}  \right]
\end{align*}

Like in others books we write, for some $a \in \mathcal{R}$
\begin{align*}
P\{ X < a\} = P\left[ \{ x \in \mathcal{R} : X(x) < a \} \right]
\end{align*}

Similarly, we can define for $\{ X > a\}$, $\{ X = a\}$, etc. In general, if $\phi$ is a property well define in the range of the RV $X$ we write
\begin{align*}
P\{ \phi(X) \} = P\left[ \{ x \in \mathcal{R} : \phi(X(x)) \text{ is true} \} \right]
\end{align*}

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I know what a PMF is, but in this book is define next to the definition that I've shared (and never talk about density function yet). My doubt is if there is some concept that I never heard about and "positive mass" means another thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context *mass* is synonymous with *probability*. A single point $X \in \mathcal R$ is said to have *positive mass* if the one-point event $\{X\}$ has positive probability, i.e. $P\{X\} > 0$. (I think I wrote the notation correctly there, but your quotation from the book is too brief to be sure about the meaning of all the notation; so if my use of the notation is incorrect in the context, let me know, and perhaps also give some explanation of the notation.)

I know nothing about that book, but if this is the first time that the word "mass" has occurred then I would say it could have been explained better.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking that synonymous too. Before this point I've found just one use of the word "mass' in an example wich says "If $P$ assings equal mass to..." and it continues with point events. Sorry, I thought that notation was not relevant in my question. When it uses brackets it's beacause is working with the probability of some set with more that one point and this set is constructed from the RV. Anyway, your have answered my question, thanks a lot!